# Unable to create a copy of a Task; Shared Activities is on

Tags: apex, tasks

I have a scenario (OpenCTI, but no matter(?)) where sometimes Tasks are created that are associated to the wrong Contact record/WhoId.  I understand that I cannot reassign the WhoId as Shared Activities has been turned on in our org, so I am trying to do the following:

1. Identify the troublesome Tasks
2. Copy the relevant values to a new Task, and assign the correct WhoId
3. Insert the new Task
4. Delete the old Task

I'm not getting any errors (using Database.Insert() on the new Tasks, and outputting any errors that occur if Database.SaveResult.IsSuccess() == false), but neither am I seeing the new Tasks.

Before I post code, any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I have it working now, actually; I'll post my solution when this go-live calms down.